# How to go about making a 3D contour map

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, 3d

Relatively new to graphic design; I wanted to ask how to go about creating a 3D contour map reminiscent of this hand-cut art piece. Is it something that requires 3D software like Dimension or Blender, or can this be done in photoshop/illustrator?[image: example here]

Comment: You can do something like this creating the shapes by hand and adding shadows in either PS or AI, but you're better off using a 3D software if you want a similarly complex result in a much shorter amount of time.

Comment: I've seen a couple of tutorials for this in Blender. Like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aJW8aroznqM and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wavyS3Xe1YU. I would not do this in PS or AI.

Comment: @AndrewH,  Thank you so much for the videos, that effect was exactly what I was looking for. As a follow-up question, if I am trying to create a specific shape from a contour map that I already have (lets say a contour map of the US), would it be possible to create the outline first in illustrator and then extrude that in blender?

Comment: Photoshop can make it. You draw an elevation map where greyhades present the elevation levels. You can get random one by blurring and posterizing few white splashes painted on a black background.  Posterizing generates discrete elevation levels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest doing this in Blender. If you want to manually do this, you can export your design from Illustrator and bring it into Blender. This will require basic knowledge of Blender.

1. Export your design as an SVG file. I created this with blend.

[image: Illustrator file]

2. In Blender go to File -> Import -> .svg
3. Select all of your curves and go to Object -> Set Origin -> Origin to Center of Mass (Surface)
4. In the Object Data Properties, add some Extrude under the Geometry tab. With all svg objects selected, right click on the extrude option and select "Copy to Selected". This will add the extruded info to all your svg shapes.

[image: Copy to selected]

5. Move the SVG curves up.

[image: SVG final]

Comment: Thank you so much for this tutorial. I appreciate it so much, it was so straight-forward.

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to consider the free program [flatfab](http://flatfab.com/). (Windows, Mac, Linux)

[image: flatfab gallery image]
Image from linked site.

The program has astonishing flexibility in design and also allows one to import SVG files for editing and manipulation.